# Angular 2 and Jasmine unit testing: cannot get the innerHtml

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using one of the examples that test a component 'WelcomeComponent':

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService }       from './model/user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-welcome',
     template: '<h3>{{welcome}}</h3>'
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
    welcome = '-- not initialized yet --';
    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.welcome = this.userService.isLoggedIn ?
            'Welcome  ' + this.userService.user.name :
            'Please log in.';
    }
}
```

This is the test case, i am checking if the 'h3' contains the user name 'Bubba':

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';

import { UserService }       from './model/user.service';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';


describe('WelcomeComponent', () => {

    let comp: WelcomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<WelcomeComponent>;
    let componentUserService: UserService; // the actually injected service
    let userService: UserService; // the TestBed injected service
    let de: DebugElement;  // the DebugElement with the welcome message
    let el: HTMLElement; // the DOM element with the welcome message

    let userServiceStub: {
        isLoggedIn: boolean;
        user: { name: string }
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        // stub UserService for test purposes
        userServiceStub = {
            isLoggedIn: true,
            user: { name: 'Test User' }
        };

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [WelcomeComponent],
            // providers:    [ UserService ]  // NO! Don't provide the real service!
            // Provide a test-double instead
            providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub }]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;

        // UserService actually injected into the component
        userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);
        componentUserService = userService;
        // UserService from the root injector
        userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
        //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
        el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement; // de.nativeElement;
    });


    it('should welcome "Bubba"', () => {
        userService.user.name = 'Bubba'; // welcome message hasn't been shown yet
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const content = el.querySelector('h3');
        expect(content).toContain('Bubba');
    });
});
```

When Testing and debugging the test case using Karma, If i evaluate "el.querySelector('h3') in the console it shows the following

```
<h3>Welcome  Bubba</h3>
```

How, i can get the innerHtml of the heading, since it doesn't resolve when including it in the ts file and the test case evaluates to false always.

[image]

This is what it says : *'innerHTML' doesn't exist on type 'HTMLHeadingElement*'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's because `content`

```
const content = el.querySelector('h3');
expect(content).toContain('Bubba');
```

is the `HTMLNode`, not the raw text. So you're expecting an `HTMLNode` to be a string. This will fail.

You need to extract the raw HTML either with `content.innerHTML` or `content.textContent` (to just get content between the `<h3>` tags

```
const content = el.querySelector('h3');
expect(content.innerHTML).toContain('Bubba');
expect(content.textContent).toContain('Bubba');
```

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet for clarifying that. I added more details to my question. I know that it is missing property innerHTML that should be called, but it cannot be resolved, Am I missing anything?

Comment: Do you get a runtime error? Or is it just an error in the IDE? I tested it and it works fine for me

Comment: I run it, its working. I thought that it will run since the IDE didn't resolve it. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know how to "fix" it because I can't reproduce it in my environment. But to work around it, you can do `(<any>content).innerHTML`

Comment: @Coding - re: missing prop -->  `const content = el.querySelector('h3') as HTMLElement;`  `content` now has `.innerHTML`