# How to find element by innerHtml

Tags: angular, jasmine

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227533/angular-2-and-jasmine-unit-testing-cannot-get-the-innerhtml) has a similar title to mine however in my case I need to find an element based on innerHtml, not find an element of type `<T>` and look at its innerHtml.

In the element below the only way to uniquely identify the div is based on its innerHtml.  I can not add an id because that would be too easy.  How do I find the div in the `debugElement.query` statement?

html:

```
<div *ngIf="isOn">Hello</div>
```

test:

```
  it('#clicked() should toggle #isOn', () => {
    const comp = component;
    comp.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[innerHTML] === "Hello"')); // wrong 

    const div2 = fixture.debugElement.query(x => x.attributes['innerHtml'] === "Hello"); // also wrong

    const div3 = fixture.debugElement.query(x => x.attributes['text'] === "Hello"); // also wrong


    expect(div).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't need to be inner HTML but rather text content...

Comment: `By.css` is protractor, not jasmine; there are [a number of methods on `By`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy) besides `css`. You may want to investigate those.

Comment: I am using Angular I believe it is a class defined as part of angular platform-browser. Also  I cannot find the div by text attribute.

Comment: wait, do you need to locate an element by innerHtml or to find innerHtml of the element that you already located

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I need to locate an element by innerHtml

Comment: are you sure this doesn't work https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I am not using protractor.  I removed protractor tag - very sorry about that.

Comment: if you can use xpath to locate element, I have an answer for you, let me know

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Yes, please share

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

First, this looks like a unit test so it should not have anything to do with Protractor. The way to find innerHTML between Protractor and the Angular TestBed is completely different. For example, in Protractor you have the option to use `by.cssContainingText(selector, someText)`. You do not have that with the Angular API. The `By` you are using is this one (not the Protractor one): https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/By

From what I gather, it's not possible to use plain css to find an element in this way. You may be able to use some jQuery magic to find it but that would be way more complex than what you really need.

---

Secondly, there is nothing "too easy" about adding an id attribute. This is exactly how it should be done. There is no logical reason not to do it. If this is some sort of test or something and you really can't add it, that's just flat out a ridiculous ask.  You could try using an xpath selector instead. I'm pretty sure there is a way to find an element by some partial text using xpath. I'll let you figure out how to do that. In any case, it can't be done using the plain css approach. The best and simplest solution would look something like the following:

```
<div *ngIf="isOn" id="someId">Hello</div>


it('#clicked() should toggle #isOn', () => {
  const comp = component;
  comp.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#someId'));

  expect(div.innerHTML).toEqual('Hello');
});
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer.  My bit of sarcasm about an ID being too easy was unfortunately based on circumstances beyond my control.  "You can't do this" is a valid answer if you want to update yours I will accept it.

Comment: well, I'm pretty sure you can find an element using xpath based on whether it contains some text or not. If that would work for you then you might want to check into that approach. I think you could still accomplish the same task it just wouldn't be `innerHTML`.

Comment: My question is horribly worded.  I am sorry.  I just want a way to find the div.  If I use text, or value or any other attribute I don't care.

Comment: > or value or any other attribute I don't care. That is part of the div as shown.  I can't modify the html.

Answer (score 0):

I used till now always this in Angular - will find the first element with the given text:

```js
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(e => e.nativeNode.innerText 
       && e.nativeNode.innerText.indexOf('Hello') >= 0)).toBeTruthy();
```

you might get multiple matches consider also using `nativeNode.localName` to define the HTML element type e.g. `td` or `button`

Here is my matcher I usually use for this job:

```js
function findByInnerText(text: string, type?: string): Predicate<DebugElement> {
  return e => e.nativeNode.innerText && e.nativeNode.innerText.indexOf(text) >= 0 && (!type ||  e.nativeNode.localName == type);
}

// the code changes to
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(findByInnerText('Hello', 'button'))).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
const div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div')).nativeElement;
expect(div.innerHTML).toContain('Hello');
```

Comment: Thank you however there are many divs on my page.  I want to find only the one with inner htm = Hello.

Comment: you can give your div some unique id and get it this way.
const div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#id')).nativeElement;

Answer (score -1):

You can use xpath to achieve what you're doing

Exact text match

```
//div[text()="Hello"]
```

Partial text match

```
//div[contains(text(),"Hello")]
```

And this one. I'm not entirely sure what it's matching

```
//div[contains(.,"Hello")]
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think this is supported by debugElement.